# Shift operators and c0 semigroups

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am asked where the bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (with sup norm) with the right shift operators ( $T_t(f)(x)=f(x-t)$ ) form a c0 semigroup.
I believe the answer is no, but I am struggling to find a Counterexample. Could someone help out?
Thanks. Lachlan

Comment: If it were $C0$, then, for every $f$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there would exist $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 \le y -x < \delta$. Can you think of a function that might not satisfy such a condition?